# TypeError 'undefined' is not an object in Javascript / Jquery JSON parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Javascript/JQuery noob here, so apologies.

I'm using `.ajax` to get a JSON object then the code below to loop through and append the fields to the page. Easy.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $("#div-ipos").append(
        "<img src=" + item.user.avatar_small_url + ">&nbsp;"
        + item.user.first_name 
        + "<hr /><br />"
    );
});
```

It works and the output is as expected, complete with the avatar path passed into an `<img>` tag.

However I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'item.user.avatar_small_url')

What do I need to do to that variable to make it behave properly in this context?

Comment: Use `item.user` instead of `item.sender`? The latter seems to be `undefined`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Apologies - corrected, was using wrong copy/paste. Please ignore! :)

Comment: Are some of the items in your JSON object missing their `user` property? In that case, you will have to test for that situation in your loop.

Comment: Have you tried console.log( item )? It should give you the exact hierarchy of the object.

Comment: Ok, weirdly now I'm getting 'cant find variable item' in console, but also OPTIONS [path to JSON] resource failed to load - yet I can get the path just fine using CURL and see the JSON returned! ARRRGH!

Comment: Response from CURL is:


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200

then the JSON payload...

But from JQUERY it's not working - it was working last night when I posted this question with no code changes! :(

Comment: Ok, clue was that 'nothing had changed' ie: server side problem. It's resolved now, so data is coming in - just still getting the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `console.log(data);` before your `$.each` to check what's in it. Most likely the server response contains an extra array element with no user. So the JSON could look like:

```
[{"user":{"avatar_small_url":"foo","first_name":"bar"}},
 {"user":{"avatar_small_url":"bar","first_name":"foo"}},
 {"something_other_than_user":9000}]
```

See how the last array element doesn't have a "user". If you have access to the server code, you may want to modify it so there is always a user, or you may modify your Javascript so that it exits early if the user field doesn't exist with something like: `if(typeof item.user == 'undefined') return;`

Comment: This is the case - both are within 'user' within 'item', but there are other fields at the next level up, not within 'user'. How does this affect item.user.avatar_small_url though?

Comment: @evilswan What does `console.log(data);` output?

Comment: says: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data"

Comment: @evilswan Is that after the fix on the server-side?

Comment: @evilswan It would be really helpfully to see the json returned from your server. If it's small post it here, if it's huge try making a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ and linking me to it.

Comment: @paul.p.r.o Same result after server-side fix. JSON is at pastebin http://pastebin.com/eZDWF7sx

Comment: @evilswan There is no "user" in your `item`. That is why `item.user` is undefined. `item.sender.avatar_small_url` is valid. So is `item.recipient.avatar_small_url`. But not `item.user.avatar_small_url`.

Comment: @Paul.p.r.o confusion from the API changes (.sender. did exist, now it's .user.) - now i'm not getting any errors, wonder if it was actually a server-side problem returning mangled JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either item.user is not defined, or item is not defined.  Have you checked the value of item?  I think you are expecting it to be something that it is not.

Comment: Oh I know how each works, but you need to check the value of item to make sure you know what the value of it is.  Clearly this is a mismatch between what you are expecting and what you are getting.

Comment: How can I output the contents of 'item' to the console to check?

Answer (score 0):

before fetching check using if condition whether key is present in that array as below

```
if( key in User)
{
    User[key]
}
```